Does it required donwtime while decreasing insync replica value in AWS MSK Cluster?
I have a MSK Cluster with 2 RF and 2 minISR values and there are multiple topics on which many producers and consumers are consuming messages.
As we should always have minISR value as RF-1, so I need to decrease this value from 2 to 1 on a running cluster.
Does it will impact existing data? or if there is any downtime required during this change?
Any help/pointer will be appreciated.
